# Sum for page function displaying zero

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I have one report containg 4 subreports and in one subreport i used sum for page function  in details footer
section  but it displaying only zero.  So is there any suggestions to resolve this.

Thanks

I tried to use same function in other sections also but not working .